# jQuery plugin "lazy" fails to load two jQuery plugins with $.getJSON calls in each of them: too much recursion ONLY in Firefox

Tags: jquery, recursion, jsonp, getjson, lazy-evaluation

Plugin: jQuery lazy()

I ask here because the project page itself seems to be dead.

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. embed two jQuery-Plugins that are both using the $.getJSON function
results in a "too much recursion error" in firefox. If the same scripts are
referenced with lazy it works fine. Problem only persits in firefox.
2. See example here:

http://www.marctv.de/lazybug/lazy.htm

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
Expected: both getJSON calls should work ok. But with lazy I get a "too
much recursion" error.

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
latest lazy version. Error can be reproduced with all jquery versions.

What can we do? Any ideas?

Comment: Please link to the plugin in the question

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to link to the project page because of the allowed amount of links. Here it is: code.google.com/p/jquery-lazy

Comment: And yes, this is a bug report. But the project page is dead and we use this plugin on our site but are not able to track the problem down to its origin. Any suggestions would be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found that the recursion happens on line 111 in proxy() function. I solved this by redownloading plugin. You can try patching your code with this:

```
if( $.lazy.archive[src].status === 'loaded' ) {

  $.lazy.archive[src].status = 'unloaded';
  $.each(this,function(){
    $(this)[name].apply(self,arg);
  });

}
```